# How does one customize Kubuntu Search and Launch (with the Plasma-Netbook interface)?

Tags: kubuntu, customization, plasma-netbook

[image: kubuntu search and launch]

How do I change the default icons (boxed, see arrow) or How do I remove them? I have tried unlocking and customizing the page, but haven't had much success.

OS: Ubuntu 11.04 with kubuntu-desktop installed (using Plasma-Netbook).

Comment: excellent wallpaper & theme - what are they?

Comment: @fossfreedom Wallpaper: "There is rain on the Table" by Riccardo laco nelli theme: seamless. Both available as updates from the theme  manager and the configure option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can just delete (by clicking the minus sign that's displayed when you hover over an icon there) or drag icons from the launch area below as shown here: www.youtube.com/watch?v=9VCX6S-ndKA
Or you can simply click on the star to have an icon added to your favorites above.

Answer (score 1):

the whole point of these files ~/.kde/share/config/plasma-desktop-appletsrc  and plasma-desktoprc
after working with these files, now it looks much better